# Android Studio show errors on Operands.DOUBLE

Tags: double, operands

```
PLUS("+", Operands.DOUBLE, 0) {
    public Double resolve(Double f1, Double f2) {
        return Double.valueOf(f1.doubleValue() + f2.doubleValue());
    }
},
```

The `Operand.DOUBLE` keeps showing an error.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you include the error message in your question?

Comment: No error message, it just shows error in every java activity for the "Operands.DOUBLE".